# opensearch dashboards (kibana) - start docker container with index pattern pre-configured

Tags: amazon-opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I have a docker-compose file containing opensearch:2.7 and opensearch-dashboards:2.7

```
services:
  opensearch:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch
  opensearch-dashboards:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards
    ports:
    - published: 8094
      target: 5601
```

I would like for the opensearch dashboard to configure an index pattern on startup.

I noticed that the UI will allow me to export my index pattern.

[image: export index pattern from saved object]

And then import that index pattern later.

[image: import saved object to re-create an index pattern]

Using the UI, I can successfully re-create the index-patter.

Is there a way to perform this import via docker-compose?

- Can the exported index pattern be mounted into the docker container?
- Is there an opensearch dashboards API call to trigger the import?

### Additional information:

- I tried a [solution documented in the OpenSearch forum](https://forum.opensearch.org/t/can-we-use-kibana-rest-apis-to-create-the-dashboards-programmatically-in-opensearchdashboard/7397/4).

```
curl -X POST \
     -H "osd-xsrf: true" \
     "http://admin:admin@localhost:8094/api/saved_objects/_import?overwrite=true" \
     --form file=@data/export.ndjson
```

The action appears to work. Unfortunately, this does not create a saved object or an index pattern.

```
{"successCount":1,"success":true,"successResults":[{"type":"index-pattern","id":"62df61e0-ea0b-11ed-b0ee-5f4ec07e6377","meta":{"title":"ecs*","icon":"indexPatternApp"},"overwrite":true}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [post](https://forum.opensearch.org/t/can-we-use-kibana-rest-apis-to-create-the-dashboards-programmatically-in-opensearchdashboard/7397/4) I referenced above helped me to solve this issue.

```
services:
  opensearch:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch
  opensearch-dashboards:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards
    ports:
    - published: 8094
      target: 5601
  init:
    image: curlimages/curl
    container_name: init
    environment:
    - DOMAIN=my.domain
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/sh
      - '-c'
      - |
          URL=http://admin:admin@$HOSTNAME.$$DOMAIN:8094
          status_code=$$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null $$URL/app/home)
          echo $$status_code
          sleep 2
          while [ $$status_code -ne 200 ]
          do
            status_code=$$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null $$URL/app/home)
            echo $$status_code
            sleep 2
          done
          cat > /tmp/indexpattern.json << HERE
          {
            "attributes": {
              "title": "ecs-*",
              "timeFieldName": "@timestamp"
            }
          }
          HERE
          curl --silent -H "osd-xsrf: true" \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
            -H "securitytenant: Global" \
            -d "@/tmp/indexpattern.json" \
            "$URL/api/saved_objects/index-pattern/ecs-*"
          echo 'index pattern imported'
    depends_on:
    - opensearch
    - opensearch-dashboards
```